# Copying file (img/doc) from a specific path to another in Android

Tags: android, file-io

I've a functionality in my application in which I save a doc/img file path in my database. This file is lying in a folder (E.g. "/mnt/sdcard/MyApp/MyItem/test.png"). Now what i want to do is to copy this file to other folder (E.g. /mnt/sdcard/MyApp/MyItem/Today/test.png).

Right now I am using the code below but it's not working :

```
private void copyDirectory(File from, File to) throws IOException {


    try {
        int bytesum = 0;
        int byteread = 0;

            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(to);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1444];
            while ((byteread = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                bytesum += byteread;
                fs.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
            }
            inStream.close();
            fs.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

and on button click am using the following code :

`File sourceFile = new File(fileList.get(0).getAbsolutePath); //comes from dbs
File targetFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyApp/MyItem/Today/");
copyDirectory(sourceFile,targetFile, currDateStr);`

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Try calling fs.flush();

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me.

```
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

And one more thing have you added in **Manifest file** **permission to write to external storage.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup got it working, I was not giving file name while copying  the files, and didnt really look at  error log, got it working now thanks. And yea the above code works just fine.